# appending a float to a stringstream in cpp

Tags: c++, floating-point, stringstream

I am trying to write a sentence inside a stringstream. Here is my  sketch:

```
stringstream is;
float position_angle0;

position_angle0=12.5;

is << "setpos1 0 %d ", int(position_angle0);
```

I guess there is something wrong because it seems not working. Can you please tell me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Standard streams do not take type format specifiers – there's no need, as they're already implicitly type-safe.

```
is << "setpos1 0 " << static_cast<int>(position_angle0) << ' ';
```

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

```
is << "setpos1 0 " << static_cast<int>(position_angle0);
```